# Is there anyway to create back custom ViewController Class files from Storyboard Scene?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I just looking for a feature which creates back Custom ViewController class files from Storyboard Scene, i.e after i dragged all required ViewController components from objects library into Stoaryboard.

Is there any way we can create new custom view controller Class files (.h and .m) from either Storyboard utility window or by command line ?

Answer (score 2):

That would be nice, but no. The closest is File->New, which isn't that close... and in the current version of Xcode creates a view controller designed to be created programatially rather than with a Storyboard. Might be worth raising a [Radar with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. How to raise a Radar with Apple?